# Program is crashing because of scanf_s in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio, scanf, dev-c++

I just started a while ago with C language because my University has a few programming lessons. I knew a little of C from High School when we were programming it in Dev C++ program. Now we need to use Visual Studio for it and next program I wrote works fine in Dev C++ but crashes after entering name. In dev C++ I remove `_s` from `strcat` and `scanf` and it works perfect. Can somebody help me with this problem ? This program is about entering a name and it should randomly set you in one of those two teams.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int maxPlayers = 16, player, teamForming, numPlayer1 = 0, numPlayer2 = 0;
    char blueTeam[256] = "", redTeam[256] = "", name[16];
    for (player = 1; player <= maxPlayers; player++) {
        printf("\nEnter a name of %d. player : ", player);
        scanf_s(" %s", name);
        teamForming = rand() % 2;
        if (teamForming == 0) {
            if (numPlayer1 == 8) {
                strcat_s(redTeam, name);
                strcat_s(redTeam, " ");
                numPlayer2++;
                break;
            }
            strcat_s(blueTeam, name);
            strcat_s(blueTeam, " ");
            numPlayer1++;
        } else {
            if (numPlayer2 == 8) {
                strcat_s(blueTeam, name);
                strcat_s(blueTeam, " ");
                numPlayer1++;
                break;
            }
            strcat_s(redTeam, name);
            strcat_s(redTeam, " ");
            numPlayer2++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nBlue team : %s.\n", blueTeam);
    printf("\nRed team : %s.\n", redTeam);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe `scanf_s` requires two arguments for `s`, `S`, `c`, and `C` formats.  The first is the result pointer (the same as `scanf`), and the second is a buffer size argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf_s` and `scanf` have slightly different semantics: for `s` and `[` formats, you must pass the size of the destination array:

```
scanf_s(" %s", name, sizeof(name));
```

Similarly, `strcat_s` takes as a third argument between the destination array and the source string, the count of elements in the destination array.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int maxPlayers = 16, player, teamForming, numPlayer1 = 0, numPlayer2 = 0;
    char blueTeam[256] = "", redTeam[256] = "", name[16];
    for (player = 1; player <= maxPlayers; player++) {
        printf("\nEnter a name of %d. player : ", player);
        scanf_s(" %s", name, sizeof(name));
        teamForming = rand() % 2;
        if (teamForming == 0) {
            if (numPlayer1 == 8) {
                strcat_s(redTeam, sizeof(redTeam), name);
                strcat_s(redTeam, sizeof(redTeam), " ");
                numPlayer2++;
                break;
            }
            strcat_s(blueTeam, sizeof(blueTeam), name);
            strcat_s(blueTeam, sizeof(blueTeam), " ");
            numPlayer1++;
        } else {
            if (numPlayer2 == 8) {
                strcat_s(blueTeam, sizeof(blueTeam), name);
                strcat_s(blueTeam, sizeof(blueTeam), " ");
                numPlayer1++;
                break;
            }
            strcat_s(redTeam, sizeof(redTeam), name);
            strcat_s(redTeam, sizeof(redTeam), " ");
            numPlayer2++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nBlue team : %s.\n", blueTeam);
    printf("\nRed team : %s.\n", redTeam);
    return 0;
}
```